# How to flag identical question as duplicate if both don't have accepted or upvoted answers?

Tags: feature-request, exact-duplicates

Just had a case during review process, where two identical questions, both asked by first time users, appeared in my queue. Yet, I can not flag one as duplicate of the other since neither has an accepted or upvoted answer.

In my opinion, it would help, if I could flag such a question as duplicate. Particularly, if it's phrased identically.

In any case, it would be nice to see identical titles (and question text) pop up in the list of possible duplicates. If I hadn't gotten both right after each other for review, I wouldn't have known about it.

In the end, I flagged the second question for moderator attention. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: This [Mother Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201849/how-to-handle-a-deliberate-duplicate-question) suggests that flagging for moderator attention is the appropriate course of action (w.r.t. flagging, it does suggest trying to figure out why one doesn't have an answer, for example)

Comment: Not that it changes a lot, just to explain: They were both homework style questions without any effort shown by the asking person. Since they were absolutely identical, either two persons copy-pasted their homework from the same source into this site or it was the same person asking twice. Hopefully just a rare case.